# Parabolic mirrors used in pair to produce much higher intensity light beam ready for transmission?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, thought-experiment, intensity

If a parabolic mirror is used to concentrate sunlight  approximately to a focus point why can't an another smaller parabolic mirror be used to reparalelise the beams that are leaving the focal point and depending of the area cross-section finaly get all possible desired densities of the reparalelized beam? Although that high intensity i.e. density reparalelized beams can reach longer distances to transfer energy(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it can be done although it is rarely used with two parabolic mirrors instead the Gregorian (parabolic + elliptic) or the Cassegrain (parabolic + hyperbolic) systems are used. There are some other variations on the idea, see Schwarzschild or Ritchey-Chretien  systems [1], etc. to increase the field of view. The parabolic+parabolic combination has the disadvantage that its off-axis aberration, coma, is worse than the other two resulting in a very narrow FOV. Also the common focus is located between the two mirrors that is a rather inconvenient place. Compare P+P with P+H or P+E the latter two can bring the focus $out$ behind the primary mirror a much more convenient location.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritchey%E2%80%93Chr%C3%A9tien_telescope

Comment: So the smaller the second mirror less shielding....

Comment: what do you mean by shielding?

Comment: I followed Your link and as I understood off axis aberation shows up when the beam is not paralel to the axis... but for  sun energy could that mirror(telescope) move following the sun so there is no that aberration... then piece of cake, the reparalelised beam passes trough a hole in the center of the primary mirror and then there is only matter of two flat mirrors to manipulate the reparalelized beam...first to make it position at a certain angle transferred to the second which can be used to move the beam in all possible directions... Am I wrong?

Comment: By shielding I meant that the smaller mirror blocks the sunlight arriving to the larger mirror...

Comment: yes, the smaller mirror (the sub-reflector) blocks the incoming light and then in the main reflector you need an axial hole about the size of the sub-reflector to capture the "resized" but parallel collimated rays on the other side of the primary mirror. The rather narrow FOV may still be a problem because the sun is not point-like and if you move the telescope a control loop cannot just sit in the "middle" right on the axis pointing at the target (sun). Anyhow your idea of having two paraboloids to resize a collimated beam is a valid one.